# My site isn't responsive - can't figure out why

Tags: css, responsive-design

I really can't find out why my site isn't responsive. When i test it in Firefox and Chrome, it seems to be, but when i test it out on my phone, it's just like desktop. I have tried media queries that responded just fine when i tested it in Firefox, but not on my phone.

link the site: http://kantina.dk/career/
CSS: http://kantina.dk/career/style.css

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the [CSS file](http://kantina.dk/career/style.css) you linked, there are no media queries, just a few styles. If you're interested, [this](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/) is a great article to help you with responsive web design and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the `Viewport` meta tags in your `<head>` section?

```
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/>
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0` in a meta viewport by default. It prevents `pinch-zoom` and should only be done for good reasons. @user3006758 I suggest you remove that section.

Comment: @hexalys thanks, i made the changes.